# How to build GCC 4.8.x on Mac OS X host for MIPS target

Tags: gcc, osx-mavericks, binutils

I am trying to build GCC / binutils for a MIPS target platform on a Mac OS X host running (10.9) x86_64.  I have downloaded the latest version of binutils and GCC to my knowledge, and I have also installed GCC 4.8.2 via homebrew.

However, so far I have been unsuccessful in building GCC / binutils for MIPS arch on a OS X host.

I tried setting the CC environment variable to point to the gcc version installed via homebrew, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Has anyone created a step by step guide for this procedure?

Comment: You might find [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) to be a useful resource. It's not clear if you want a hosted cross-compiler (with kernel, libc system headers, etc) or a free-standing 'bare metal' gcc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I was able to get GCC built on OS X for a target architecture of MIPS.  I wrote a step by step guide of the procedure [here](http://www.theairportwiki.com/index.php?title=Building_a_cross_compile_of_GCC_for_MIPS_on_OS_X).

Comment: The link is giving me a 404 :|

Comment: weird, try this, http://www.theairportwiki.com/index.php?title=Building_a_cross_compile_of_GCC_for_MIPS_on_OS_X